# Disabling/Enabling Submit Button pending Struts File-Download Action

Tags: jquery, struts-1

I found some bits-and-pieces regarding disabling the Submit button for form processing (to avoid a double form submission), but it doesn't help my particular case:

Suppose I disable 'Submit' in jQuery on form submission,

JS/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

         alert('In Document.ready');

        // Initially enable the Submit button
        $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);

        $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
            // Disable Submit button on form submit
            $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
          });
    });
</script>
```

Form HTML

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="/generate.do">

                    <label>Number</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="number" maxlength="50" value="" title="Enter Number">
                    <html:submit value="Go"/>

</form>
```

This works -- the button gets disabled. I have a Struts Action class on the server-side that handles this form.

The Struts Action result is to return a File Download. I write to the Response per the usual Struts guidelines and get my Save As dialog

Struts Action:

```
InputStream is = getImageBytes();

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"");

// Write to Response Stream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
is.close();
os.flush();     
// Response was handled within the action, so set forward = null
forward = null;
```

**Problem:** The Submit button doesn't get re-enabled after I come back from the Action, it's still disabled. I don't get my page-startup jQuery alert box on coming back, so the page hasn't been refreshed.

I can't forward or sendRedirect anymore with this forward, I get these errors:

For example,
(1) Forward

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:328)
```

for

```
ActionForward forwardSuccess = mapping.findForward("success");
forwardSuccess.setRedirect(false);
return forwardSuccess;
```

(2) SendRedirect

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:494)
```

**Goal:** The goal is to return a File-Download result from the server-side action, but intercept it somehow in jQuery **to re-enable the Submit button** in the form when the result comes back.

Comment: Which version of Struts?

Comment: This is Struts 1.3

Comment: This is the only way to output a File Download response in Struts 1.3 which this app is using.

Comment: You can redirect downloading to another servlet.